# ng-repeat is not binding values into Dom?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am loading data dynamically to ng-repeat so once i receive data its not binding it to `ul` , i know sometime it happens if you have duplicate indexes but in below case i am not sure what is happening, Any idea ?

main.html

```
<div>
    <ul ng-repeat="message in data track by index">
        <li>{{message}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

ctrl.js

```
angular.module('loggingApp').controller('DitCtrl',function ($scope,DitFactory) {
    'use strict';
    DitFactory.getLogs().then(function (response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
        console.log($scope.data);
    });
});
```

console.log

```
printing data in console

["test.txt", "test1.txt", "test2.txt", "test3.txt", "test4.txt"]
```

Comment: Did you try `ng-repeat="message in $scope.data track by index"` ?

Comment: nope its not displaying anything

Comment: try `$scope.data.messageData = response.data;` and `ng-repeat="message in data.messageData track by index"`

Answer (score 5):

Your ng-repeat needs to look like this:

```
ng-repeat="message in data track by $index"
```